# Is it possible to call a function but ignore all it's print()-commands?

Tags: r

I am using a function from a package that prints alot of stuff into the console. Is it possible to use this function but ignore all print-commands?

**Example:**

```
f <- function(x){
print("Starting process 1/5")
print("Starting process 2/5")
print("Starting process 3/5")
print("Starting process 4/5")
print("Starting process 5/5")
Save <<- x+2
}
```

**Desired Output:**

Save is set to x+2 but nothing is printed to the console.

**Stuff i have tried but didn't work:**

```
invisible(f(1))

sink(f(1))
```

Is there a way to solve this without extra packages or without beeing able to change the function itself?

Comment: You can redefine print: ```print = function(x){} ```.  I would wrap this in another function though, since it's a little dirty.

Comment: It seems odd that a function would be using `print` instead of `message` to output messages to the console. If the function uses `message` it is easy to simply use `suppressMessages`. (This doesn't help the problem but is more of a comment on the overly verbose function)

Comment: what about `capture.output(f(1), file='NUL')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `invisible(capture.output(f(1)))`

Answer (score 1):

```
junk <- capture.output(f(1))
Save
# 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use `sink` is to setup a file to which all the console outputs will be printed, for example

```
sink("r-output")
```

will tell R to start writing all its console outputs after this line into a file `r-output` in the current directory (you can change the name of the file to whatever you want).

If you then want to start writing the R outputs in the console again, you will need to stop the `sink` process by calling again the function but without providing a file name:

```
sink()
```

Note that this will only write outputs such as those made by `print` to this file, but will still print any messages, warnings, or errors, in the console. You could send these too by specifying `type = c("output","message")` in your first call to `sink`.

Comment: In this case it's not what i want to use. Thanks for clarifying how sink() works.